# Get name of type as a string

Tags: python

I have developed a function which operates on supplied input and if it doesn't find the type of input data as unicode it has to return that input data type unicode is required. I can do it by hard coding it to unicode but in future if I want to change required data type I dont want to change that string accordingly. Therefore I kept required data types of input variables in different file and if it doesn't match, it returns required data type from that file. But it returns something like

```
Required Data Type - <type 'unicode'>
```

Instead of `<type 'unicode'>` I want it to return just `unicode`. Please suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `__name__` attribute of type:

```
>>> s = unicode(1)
>>> type(s).__name__
'unicode'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is an alternative and works with user-defined classes :

```
s.__class__.__name__
```

Example :

```
class A :
    pass

a = A()
type(a).__name__ # 'instance'
a.__class.__name # 'A'

s = u"string"
type(s).__name__ # 'unicode'
s.__class.__name # 'unicode'
```